# Python threading for wheel encoders on a Robot

Tags: python, python-multithreading, robot

I'm writing the code for a robot which my college is entering into a competition. I'm currently trying to build some wheel encoders using reflectance sensors. I realised a while back that I would probably need to use threading to achieve this, seeing as the robot needs to monitor both the left and right encoders at the same time. The code below is what I have so far:

```
from __future__ import division
import threading
import time
from sr import *
R = Robot()

class Encoder(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, motor, pin, div=16):
        self.motor = motor
        self.pin = pin
        self.div = div
        self.count = 0
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        while True: 
            wait_for(R.io[0].input[self.pin].query.d)
            self.count += 1

    def rotations(self, angle, start_speed=50):
        seg = 360/self.div
        startcount = self.count
        current_dist = angle #Distance away from target
        R.motors[self.motor].target = start_speed
        while current_dist > 360:
            newcount = self.count - startcount
            current_dist = angle - newcount*seg
            R.motors[self.motor].target = 50
        while abs(current_dist) > seg/2:  
            newcount = self.count - startcount
            current_dist = angle - newcount*seg
            current_speed = start_speed * current_dist / 360
            if current_speed < 5:
                R.motors[self.motor].target = 5
            else:
                R.motors[self.motor].target = current_speed
        R.motors[self.motor].target = 0

WheelLeft = Encoder(0,0)
WheelLeft.start()
WheelRight = Encoder(1,3)
WheelRight.start()

WheelRight.rotations(720)
WheelLeft.rotations(720)
```

The sr module is provided by Southampton University, who are running the competition. It allows us to interact with the robot's hardware.

Now, the threads which get created seem to allow the two reflectance sensors to be monitored separately. This bit of code: `R.io[0].input[self.pin].query.d` works out whether the value coming from the reflectance sensor has changed. The 'rotations' method turns the wheel through a certain angle by constantly checking how many degrees the wheel has already turned through, and slowing it down as it reaches the end. I would like both wheels to start turning when I run the program, and then slow down and stop when they have gone through 2 rotations. Currently though, when I run the program, one wheel starts turning and slows down and stops, followed by the other wheel. It seems to me like the 'rotations' method is not running in a thread, like the 'run' method is. Is it only the code under the 'run' method that runs in a thread, or is it the whole class?

If it helps, I've been following this tutorial: http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Python/Basic-Threading-in-Python/1/

Also, I would like to know why it is possible to start a thread only with `Encoder(0,0).start()`. Why do you not have to create an object using the class (e.g. `Thread = Encoder(0,0).start()` for a new thread to be created?

Sorry if the terminoligy I've used isn't up to scratch, as you can probably tell I'm quite new to threading, and programming in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Encoder(0,0).start()` is a call to the method to start the thread. In turn, this method calls your `run` implementation, which doesn't use the `rotations` method. If you want to do so, then you have to call it in the while loop of `run`.

With `Thread = Encoder(0,0).start()` you store the value retrieved from that call (which is None), but to get it you need to start the new thread first anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The run method *is* the thread of execution.

If you want something else to happen in that thread, you have to call it from `Encoder.run()`.

Oh, and `Encoder(0,0).start()` *does* create an object. Just because you didn't bind that object to a local variable doesn't mean it doesn't exist. If it didn't exist you couldn't call its `start` method.

You have to be very careful about its lifetime though, without a local variable keeping it alive.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend from SR's [`Poll`](https://github.com/PeterJCLaw/srobo-pyenv/blob/master/pyenv/pylib/sr/poll.py) class so that it can be used in a `wait_for`:

```
import poll

class Encoder(poll.Poll):
    def __init__(self, motor, pin, div=16):
        self.motor = motor
        self.pin = pin
        self.div = div
        self.count = 0
        self.target_reached = False

        # kick off a thread to count the encoder ticks
        self.counter_thread = threading.Thread(target=self._update_count)
        self.counter_thread.start()

    def _update_count(self):
        while True: 
            wait_for(R.io[0].input[self.pin].query.d)
            self.count += 1

    def rotations(self, angle, start_speed=50):
        if not self.target_reached:
            raise Exception("Last motion still in progress!")

        self.target_reached = False

        # kick off a thread to control the speed
        self.angle_thread = threading.Thread(
            target=self._update_speeds,
            args=(angle, start_speed)
        )
        self.angle_thread.start()

    def _update_speeds(self, angle, start_speed):
        # control the motor speed as before
        ...

        # let things know we're done
        self.target_reached = True

    # implement poll methods
    def eval(self):
        return (self.target_reached, None)
```

Which then lets you do:

```
wheelLeft = Encoder(0,0)
wheelRight = Encoder(1,3)

wheelRight.rotations(720)
wheelLeft.rotations(720)

wait_for(wheelRight & wheelLeft)
```

Note that an encoder isn't itself a thread - it's a "has a" relationship, not an "is a" relationship